# tibble table display issue when using R in jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, tidyverse, tibble

I just started using R in Jupyter notebook. There seems to be some issue displaying tibble table. 
for example,

```
mtcars
```

Everything is normal. 
If mtcars is converted to tibble,

```
car<-as_data_frame(mtcars)
car
```

The table displayed is totally screwed....
Anyone knows why? Do I need to set some options in jupyter notebook?

A follow-up question: How to control the number of rows for table output (not using head())? Is there any notebook options I can set? Is there any way that display the whole table with some page number button like those in R notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the latest version of Jupyter Notebook? I get exactly the same printout for the base data frame and the tibble.

As for the number of rows to show, I don't know of any notebook setting. If you don't want to use `head()`, you can always do:

```
mtcars[seq.int(15),]
```

with whatever number of lines you want instead of 15.

Comment: I see. It's probably the jupyter notebook version. I'm using the notebook on the cloud. It might be the old version.